# How to create a room entity properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have created my entity for my room database and have viewed several tutorials

Some using a variable with or without an ? - what is the difference in an entity

and some using a constructor afterwards within an entity - it is necessary and what is the difference?

```
@Entity(tableName = "birthday")
data class Bday(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Name")
    var name : String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Birthday")
    var birth : String?
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is the nullable operator, which means the variable can be null. In your example:

```
var name : String?
```

It could be `"Jhon"` or `null`.

- It depends on how you want to store it in Room. So if you think sometime you will have a user that will not have a name momentarily (a draft, an edit, etc)
- Most of the time the network model obtained from an HTTP request can be saved directly to ROOM. So it depends on what the server is sending.

The constructor position is part of the Kotlin syntax, for `data class` the constructor goes in the class declaration. Data classes are recommended for DB entities because structural equality makes it easier to work `userA == userB` is a comparation of the attributes.

You should also wonder: `val` or `var` if you think you need to modify the entity later by modification the object then `var` but if you can work with immutability then that is better because structural comparison can have problems with `var`. Most of the time if you need to modify a data class using vals the `copy` method is just what you need.

I think data class documentation should help you:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html